# Is it possible to use past-tense with present-tense in the same sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I usually face this problem of using two or more tenses in one sentence. Would you please help me with the following example if it is correct:

> After I *signed*-up for the shift, I *revived* an email *mentioned* that there *is* an instruction packet included video need to be watched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

"After I signed-up for the shift, I revived an email that mentioned an instruction packet..."

The rest of it is a bit unclear.

"After I signed-up for the shift, I revived an email that mentioned an instruction packet with a video that needed to be watched"